# Select data based on minimum value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am working on a PostgreSQL database with data from car tracking which looks similar to this.

```
+--------+---------------------+-------+---------+------------+------------+
| car_id |       datetime      | trip  |  speed  |  hub1_dist |  hub2_dist |
+--------+---------------------+-------+---------+------------+------------+
|    1   | 2014-12-20 12:12:12 |   1   |    82   |     6.7    |     2.1    |
|    1   | 2014-12-20 12:12:13 |   1   |    81   |     3.5    |     4.4    |
|    1   | 2014-12-20 12:12:14 |   1   |    85   |     7.8    |     3.8    |
|    1   | 2014-12-20 17:42:51 |   2   |    82   |     4.2    |     5.4    |
|    1   | 2014-12-20 17:42:52 |   2   |    76   |     2.5    |     2.1    |
|    2   | 2014-12-21 09:24:24 |   3   |    80   |     4.5    |     6.7    |
|    2   | 2014-12-21 09:24:25 |   3   |    84   |     5.3    |     3.5    |
|    2   | 2014-12-21 09:24:26 |   3   |    83   |     8.2    |     5.1    |
+--------+---------------------+-------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Where every car has a specific `car_id`, and the `trip` changes based on that `car_id` or a change in `datetime` bigger than 5 sec.
For every data point the `speed` is registred, and the distance to a number of `hubs` are calculated

I would like to end up with a table where the `speed` is shown, based on the shortest distance to every `hub`. It should look like this:

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+
| trip  |    hub1_speed    |  speed_hubdist_2 |
+-------+------------------+------------------+
|   1   |        81        |        82        |
|   2   |        76        |        76        |
|   3   |        80        |        84        |
+-------+------------------+------------------+
```

I am currently using:

```
SELECT trip, hub1_dist, speed
FROM (
  SELECT trip, hub1_dist, speed,
         MIN(hub1_dist) OVER (PARTITION BY trip) AS MIN_hub1_dist
  FROM data_base
) t
WHERE hub1_dist = MIN_hub1_dist
```

And that works. But in some cases I have 50 `hubs`, so I have to do it 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an aggregation:

```
select trip, min(hub1_dist), min(hub2_dist), min(hub3_dist), . . . 
from data_base
group by trip;
```

You need to type out the expressions for each column.  A spreadsheet can help you generate the query.  Or, you can do something like this:

```
select string_agg(replace('min(hub@n_dist) as hub@n_dist', '@n', gs.n::text), ', ')
from generate_series(1, 50, 1) gs(n)
```

EDIT:

You can get the speed for the minimum distances using array functions:

```
select trip, min(hub1_dist),
       (array_agg(speed order by hub1_dist))[1] as speed_at_min1,
       min(hub2_dist),
       (array_agg(speed order by hub2_dist))[1] as speed_at_min2,
       min(hub3_dist),
       (array_agg(speed order by hub3_dist))[1] as speed_at_min3,
       . . . 
from data_base
group by trip;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :) I think it's almost what I want, except I need the speed corresponding to the min(hubn_dist), and not the hub_dist. I don't know how I schould use the second code together with the first.

Comment: @Vangen . . . That is easy enough.